# A riley that strives to become better

Tags: riddle

You could say my prefix aims for the top.

My infix with my suffix sets a strong foundation and just like here, seldom used on its own.

But my suffix really sounds like it puts it all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Reinforcement

You could say my prefix aims for the top.

> **Rein** sounds like *reign* which means to be the best or most important in a particular area (this explains the "you could say" part as a homophone indicator).

My infix with my suffix sets a strong foundation and just like here, seldom used on its own.

> **Forcement** which can mean compulsion (although somewhat obsolete) and compulsion is an essential ingredient in any endeavour to aim for the top.
>  As Stiv mentioned in the comments the "it" here may just refer to the infix, **for**, which is usually used along with another word in a sentence and can't really be used on its own.

But my suffix really sounds like it puts it all together.

> **Cement** - as in MacGyver88's answers

Title

> **Reinforcement** is the act of strengthening something. It also reminds me of the idea of [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning#:%7E:text=Reinforcement%20learning%20(RL)%20is%20an,supervised%20learning%20and%20unsupervised%20learning.) which is a machine learning technique that gets better at a particular task over time.

Comment: Avpr. V qvqa'g jnag gb sybbq gur cntr jvgu PRZRAG raqvat nafjref. Abg gung gurer ner gung znal zber gung zngpu. "FZRAG" jnf zl arkg gubhtug, ohg V'z bhg. Gjb'f rabhtu sbe zr.

Comment: I think you've got it +1 But I think the 'seldom used on its own' fragment refers to rot13(gur vasvk fcrpvsvpnyyl, naq vf fhccbfrq gb ersyrpg gung 'sbe' vf hfhnyyl hfrq nybat jvgu nabgure jbeq va n fragrapr naq pna'g ernyyl or hfrq ba vgf bja...)

Comment: @Stiv Ah, I see, you reckon the "it" in the sentence is the infix rather than the compound infix-suffix, that might make more sense. Will edit in with credit.

Comment: Ding Ding, we got a winner!

Answer (score 4):

Second Attempt

> REPLACEMENT

You could say my prefix aims for the top.

> REP - The more REP you earn, the closer you get to the top

My infix with my suffix sets a strong foundation and just like here, seldom used on its own.

> PLACEMENT - To set something, like a foundation? Play on PLACE and CEMENT? - Not sure

But my suffix really sounds like it puts it all together.

> CEMENT - Holds things together

Title

> Replacing bad habits or routines with new good ones? Coincidentally, I'm replacing my previous answer with what I hope is a better answer.

Previous

> ADVANCEMENT

You could say my prefix aims for the top.

> AD -  Adverts at the top of screens

My infix with my suffix sets a strong foundation and just like here, seldom used on its own.

> VAN on CEMENT - a van works best on a road

But my suffix really sounds like it puts it all together.

> CEMENT - Holds things together

Title

> ADVANCEMENT - an act of moving forward. - promotion in rank or standing; 
>  Could be used to mean: to become better.

Comment: The title makes sense too!

Comment: @Beastly, Gung'f jurer V fgnegrq sebz. I will include.

Comment: Very nice guess and very close, but not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Your first guess was closer to the actual one I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer be

> open

You could say my prefix aims for the top.

> op -- original posters aim for quality in their posts.

My infix with my suffix sets a strong foundation and just like here, seldom used on its own.

> pe and en -- physical exercise and English sets a strong foundation

But my suffix really sounds like it puts it all together.

> en -- English is what put this riddle together.

Comment: Nice answer, but not what I was thinking of.